# PHP error log showing misspelled URL

Tags: php

Bit of a strange one here. I'm looking through my PHP Error log and on a number of occasions I'm seeing the following line

`File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.org.uk/httpdocs/users/assignmnets`

The reason the file doesn't exist is that the folder is spelt wrong - it should read *assignments*, not *assignmnets*.

The thing is, I've gone through all of the code on the site and this spelling mistake doesn't appear anywhere at all, so why am I getting this error? Furthermore, there are no links to the above folder - any links point directly to the php file contained within the folder - `assignments/assignments.php`

I can't make head nor tail of it. Is this a common issue with PHP or is there something I am getting wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Double check your FULL code. Not just skim eyes, but use find function in full project. Also check database entries too.

Comment: use Ctrl+Shift+F if using SublimeText to do full project search.

Comment: Maybe someone else is trying to access it via a bookmark they might have mispelled.

Comment: Are you sure the physical folder itself is spelled correctly?

Comment: I think something externally has tried to call it and it is mispelled.

Comment: Could possibly be caused by a frequent visitor who misspelled the URL, which was then saved to their browsing history, so auto-completes to that when they try and type it in themselves? If you make a custom 404 page which logs the $_SERVER variable each time it can't find a page, you should be able to see if this is the case, for example if they are all thrown by the same user, and have no referrer

Comment: Check your webserver logs to find the URL this is being called or refered from.

Comment: It that were the case for me, I would setup a file as a mod rewrite with a message in there stating "Stop accessing this folder etc.". ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- or a 302 redirect to http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/assignments?s=t (the server admin at dictionary.com can get a "chuckle" as well when they check the referrer)

Comment: @CD001 That too hahaha! *grin*

Answer (score 0):

What kind of PHP error log is it? some custom logger function? Try using Tracy https://github.com/nette/tracy - enabling this debugger in your project with

```
Debugger::enable(Debugger::DETECT, __DIR__ . '/mylog');
```

will result in that all PHP errors will be logged as an HTML file with very verbose description of the error, including full stack trace (in production environment; on localhost, when development environment is detected, you will see the stack trace immediatelly in browser). From this you will be able to determine which part of code caused this problem next time it happens.

Don't forget to disable your custom error handler if any is in use, as it may be colliding with Tracy.